# Half-open range on array with one element

Tags: swift, swift5

```
let oneNumArr = [0]
oneNumArr[0..<0] // ArraySlice([])
oneNumArr[0..<1] // [0]
oneNumArr[1..<1] // ArraySlice([])
```

Why does both `0..0` and `1..<1` return `ArraySlice([])`?

Comment: Both `0..<0` and `1..<1` are empty ranges.

Answer (score 0):

#### First case:

```
oneNumArr[0..<0]
```

- This is from index `0` to before `0`.
- Indexes: none
- This range doesn't make sense, because you are saying include `1`, but don't include `1` in the range. It is known as an empty range.

#### Second case:

```
oneNumArr[0..<1]
```

- This is from index `0` to before `1`.
- Indexes: `0`
- This range does work.

#### Third case:

```
oneNumArr[1..<1]
```

- This is from index `1` to before `1`.
- Indexes: none
- This range doesn't make sense (same reason as first case).

See full details about Range Operators from Swift Docs [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID73).

Comment: Then `2..<2` should also be an empty range? But this time, it's throwing an error.

Comment: @chlkdst I don't know for sure, but it looks like the subscript is checked to make sure that the upper bound is `<=` to the `count - 1` of the array. If the upper bound is higher, it knows there will be an out-of-bounds error. For example, `1..<1`: the upper bound is below `1`, which fits the criteria. However, with `2..<2`, the upper bound is above `1`. Quite weird, don't worry about it.